# Java application session timeout on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web.xml

I have a Spring application with a standard cookie-based Spring authentication. I can control the session timeout on a Tomcat locally using `session-timeout` property in my project's `web.xml`. So for instance, if `session-timeout` is set to `1`, I see that the session expires after one minute.

However, when the application is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (standard war file), it looks like `session-timeout` in project's `web.xml` file has no effect. I am running load-balanced AWS environment.

Am I missing something obvious? How do I control session expiration on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Are you running on a single instance ? Or you have started more then one instance of application at beanstalk ?

Comment: @Babl, I am running load-balanced AWS environment. I have updated the question.

Comment: did you enable session stickiness? If you did, what happens when you issue two requests 5 minutes apart? Are they properly served with the same session id?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enabling stick sessions solved the issue.

However, be aware about https://stackoverflow.com/a/10502092/417297